# Creating new map

Tags: carto

Using Cartodb I copied a map to make a new one. The edits are being duplicated in both versions. Is there a way to restore the old map without impacting the new one?

Comment: When you "copied" what where the steps you did to do that? I am aware of a few options when working with maps on Cartodb. You can dupilcate, lock etc... Just trying to get more details as what you did to get where you are.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating maps should create independent maps in terms of styling, but they would still share the same source dataset.

Style changes (CartoCSS, queries applied on them, legends, elements...) should be independent, but if you are editing the data of one of your maps, take into account that you are really editing the data which lives in a dataset. Changing the data in a dataset, being it from the dataset instead or from different maps will show changes in all of them, as you are editing the underlying data.

If you need to edit the data independently, then you should create a copy of the dataset (with the Duplicate dataset option, for example) and create a map from it.